# Search by xpath and text where text is a string contained within a list

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python

I'm struggling to find a way to search a page by xpath that contains text that I've defined within a list using selenium. If I replace Role_List[y] by "WK" etc., it works fine and I can repeat it 4 times but there's a lot of code after that I wouldn't want to repeat but just gives an error when I try to use Role_List[y] but can't figure out what the problem might be.

```
Role_List=["WK","BAT","AR","BOWL"]

for y in range(4):
    z= browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'createTeamTabTitle_')and text() = Role_List[y]]")
    z.click()
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code is a raw string:

```
"//div[contains(@class,'createTeamTabTitle_') and text() = Role_List[y]]"
```

*y* is interpreted as a char, not as the loop variable.

Try:

```
"//div[contains(@class,'createTeamTabTitle_') and text() = '%s']" % (Role_List[y])
```

Or even better, just loop through the list:

```
for role in Role_List
    browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'createTeamTabTitle_') and text() = '%s']" % (role)).click()
```

Comment: Hi your code will search for Role_List["mk"] and not mk

Answer (score 1):

The array is not passed as an array but a string:

[image]

so the code is actually checking for an element that contains the text "Role_List[y]

so use below code:

```
z= browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'createTeamTabTitle_')and text() =\""+Role_List[y]+"\"]")
```

Comment: Please comment your thoughts when down voting